# create a view for getting the list of documents where end time is equal or greater than current time

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

In couchDB database I have set of docs:

Example doc is:

```
{
 "_id": "26",
 "_rev": "1-53ac67e9ec4b4ce8ffa9cd609e107aaf",
 "customer_name": "Vadilal",
 "type": "trip",
 "duration": "10 hours 27 mins",
 "end_time": "Jan 1, 2014 10:11:00 PM",
 "start_time": "Jan 11, 2014 8:46:00 AM",
}
```

If I call the view by passing current time as `key` and `type` as `trip` then I should get list of records whose `endtime` is less than or equal to current time and whose `type` is `trip`. Based on `type` being passed from the URL, I should get the data.

suppose in sql query would be like this :

```
select * from table_name where end_time>="current_time" and type='passed_trip'
```

In couchDB how can we write the View for above query???

can anyone help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, view is not a query, it is an index. So, just create a view with key `end_time` (view are sorted using the key) and query with current time as start key, and `{}` as end key. Note that your `end_time` is a human readable string which sorted lexicographically will not give you correct chronological order.

Comment: I am calling URL like ../test/_design/test/_view/test?startkey=1388617960000&endkey={}  is this correct? Here I took time in milli seconds.

Comment: Marcin, I have done some changes in my requirement can you please look into above post. please help me to figure it out, it would be great help to me. Thank you so much.